# A *.sdf database does not work with password

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-ce

I created a `*.sdf` file with password protected using Visual Studio, worked fine. I insert some data and I tried read using Visual Studio SQL editor, but when I went to the C # code that did not work.

I tried the following:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var conStr = @"data source=C:\path\db.sdf; password=<...>";
            SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conStr);
            con.Open();

            SqlCeCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from Cookies";
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.TableDirect;
            cmd.Connection = con;

            SqlCeDataReader result = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            //...
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

I getting the following error:
`The specified table does not exist. [ select * from Cookies ]`

The table structure

[image]

This returns false. Someone can point my mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Removed the "sqlite" tag - the `.sdf` file is a SQL Server Compact Edition database - has nothing to do with `sqlite`

Comment: When you say "does not work" - is there an error? Are you not getting the data you expect? What's going on?

Comment: @sq33G: `data.Read()` returns `false`

Comment: What happens when you set CommandType to TableDirect and CommandText to the name of your table?

Comment: @sq33G:In advance, thanks for you reply. CommandText as name of table works fine. But using select this not works and returns the following error: `The specified table does not exist. [ select * from Cookies ]` the table structure: http://i.imgur.com/3TwoE.png

Comment: Check your bin folder..there must be an sqlce database there and that is the one with Cookies table.

Comment: Check your bin folder..there must be an sqlce database there and that is the one with Cookies table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're specifying `System.Data.CommandType.TableDirect`.

When you change your code to use the following, you'll avoid the error you're seeing.

```
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
```

You can even exclude setting the `CommandType` property, as `Text` is the default.

`TableDirect` is an OLEDB legacy command type. Don't use it unless your command is only a table or view name. Internally, the command object will construct a `SELECT * FROM` statement, selecting all fields and all records from the specified table or view.